# Heroku - New Relic Agent not running error on rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, newrelic

First time I've seen this error when running a migration on Heroku.

```
heroku rake db:migrate --app myapp
(in /app)
New Relic Agent not running.
```

I have the New Relic addon in my app addons so would this be an issue with the heroku platform or my app?

edit: App is running on the bamboo-ree-1.8.7 stack.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to this issue, but when you're asking Heroku-related questions it is really helpful to include the stack you're on.

Comment: This sounds like a good question for support@heroku.com.

Comment: @sscirrus Yep, I had already submitted a support ticket with Heroku. Just thought someone might have had the same problem or may experience this in future since there wasn't anything I could find on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this was a simple fix. The new relic addon on Heroku stopped working and simply required me to remove and add it back to my application.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that Heroku is telling you that the New Relic Agent is not running in that environment when you run `rake`, however `rake db:migrate` is still working, so actually everything is working as it should.

Simply run your `rake db:migrate`, ignore the New Relic message, then `heroku restart` and everything should be working just fine.